# How to set up i18n translations for derived ActiveRecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, internationalization

I have the following three models:

```
class Facebook < ActiveRecord::::Base
end

class Facebook::Like < Facebook
end

class Facebook::Share < Facebook
end

class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And I want to set up the attribute translations for it, but I don't know how to be specific about the derived classes.

*config/locales/en.yml*

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    like:
      data: "Someting"
    facebook_like:
      data: "Someting else"
    facebook_share:
      data: "Again - Someting else"
```

Ok - so facebook_like and facebook_share obviously doesn't work - but what would I replace them with to be able to achieve my specific translations needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slash `/`:

```
facebook/like:
  data: "Someting else"
```